# NSString initWithData return string value in extra quotes, how to fix it?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdata, quotes

Everyone,

Method initWithData of NSString return me the value in extra quotes, how can I fix it ?
For example:

> NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData
>   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

recievedData contains SessionID and during debugging result looks like: ""33BD76C7F62B4B95805D15BF120594C1E901""
So when I try send HTTP request I get such url: http://server.com?SessionID="33BD76C7F62B4B95805D15BF120594C1E901", but it should be as
http://server.com?SessionID=33BD76C7F62B4B95805D15BF120594C1E901

How can I get string value from NSData without these outside quotes ?

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty solution.

```
result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\""
                                 withString:@""];
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But may be anyone know is there a solution to get String from NSData without these outside quotes ?